# URL Encoding Percentage Space

Tags: urlencode, space, url-encoding, percent-encoding

Twitter sharing link problem with URL Encoding. i need to share this sentence.

**i am giving you 40% discount**

i am trying this to pass from url

```
i+am+giving+you+40%+discount  

but its not working because +40%+ become %2040%%20
```

**Two percentage %% together create problem**
    What will be solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use encoded "%" -> "%25", also maybe you try some library for URL encoding.
Your url will looks like **"i%20am%20giving%20you%2040%25%20discount"**

- %20 - is a space
- %25 - % symbol

Comment: get+40%25+caa become get+40%%20caa